# How do I add a number to another everytime a loop repeats

Tags: python, loops, clock

So at school, our teacher asked us to make a program which needs a password to grant access. I have made this however i would like to improve on it by adding a loop count which increase each time it loops round heres what i have so far for the loop count, however it doesn't work.

```
import time
b=0
a='apple'

def start():
    print("enter password")
    c=input("->  ")
    if c==a:
        grant()
    else:
        delay()

def grant():
    end

def delay():
    b=b+1
    time.sleep(b)
    start()

start()
```

Comment: I seem to be missing something ... I don't see any loops here ...

Comment: He's using recursion (See `start()` in `delay()`)

Comment: Why exactly you say it doesn't work?

Comment: what is `end` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is inside here:

```
def delay():
    b=b+1
    time.sleep(b)
    start()
```

When you do `b = b + 1`, you're expecting the `b` variable at the top of the file to increase by 1, right?

You probably haven't learned this yet, but the reason why this doesn't work is because of something called [scope](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~selfpace/cs9honline/Q2/scope.html).

To fix it, you need to change your `delay` function to look like this:

```
def delay():
    global b
    b=b+1
    time.sleep(b)
    start()
```

---

From looking at your code, I take it you haven't learned how to use `while` loops yet?

Your solution of repeatedly calling `start` inside of `delay` is actually pretty clever. However, if we use a `while` loop, we can rewrite your program so that it's a little cleaner and more obvious as to what you're trying to do:

```
import time

password = 'apple'

def start():
    counter = 0
    user_guess = ''

    while user_guess != password:
        print("enter password")
        user_guess = input("->  ")
        if user_guess != password:
            counter += + 1          # Same thing as doing `counter = counter + 1`
            time.sleep(counter)

    grant()

def grant():
    print "Access granted!"

start()
```

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't recognize `b` in `delay()` because it is in global scope.

Try this:

```
def delay():
    global b
    b=b+1
    time.sleep(b)
    start()
```

Comment: Or better yet, pass it in as an argument, and return it.

Comment: Also, just so you know if the future, `b = b + 1` is the same thing as `b += 1`.  More in line with Python style guide.